# Raspberry pi not booting from updated kernel running Ubuntu 20.04. How to switch to updated kernel on Pi 4?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, raspberrypi

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. I recently did a `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` on my server and it (maybe unsucessfully) update my kernel version.

When I run `uname -a` I get:

```
Linux mail.facl.xyz 5.4.0-1082-raspi #93-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 10 14:26:26 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-.*` I get:

```
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1073-raspi                                5.4.0-1073.84                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1077-raspi                                5.4.0-1077.88                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1078-raspi                                5.4.0-1078.89                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1079-raspi                                5.4.0-1079.90                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1080-raspi                                5.4.0-1080.91                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-1081-raspi                                5.4.0-1081.92                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-1083-raspi                                5.4.0-1083.94                              arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on ARMv8 SMP
ii  linux-image-raspi                                           5.4.0.1083.113                             arm64        Raspberry Pi Linux kernel image
```

So it seems the my uname results of 5.4.0-1082-raspi, are not even installed on my raspberry pi Ubuntu. My Pi is still booting properly though.

How can I fix this and get my raspberry pi Ubuntu 20.04 to use the latest kernel of 5.4.0.1083.113?

Comment: Just to confirm, is your Pi still booting? Is it seemingly using a kernel that is not available on the repositories?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes my pi is still booting. It is seemingly using a kernel that is not available on the repos. But it is still booting.

Comment: You are not running a Ubuntu kernel but a Raspi Ubuntu kernel.